# Is it possible to have a SoA Vertex Buffer in DirectX 11?

Tags: c++, directx11, vertex-buffer

**Hi!**

I'm wondering if it is possible to structure a Vertex Buffer in a SoA approach like this

**{ x1, x2, x3 . . . xn, y1, y2, y3 . . . yn, z1, z2, z3 . . . zn }**

instead of the traditional AoS approach

**{ x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3 . . . xn, yn, zn }**

---

If that beeing the case.. Is it possible to design the `ID3D11InputLayout` like this?

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputDesc[] = {                 
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, 0,       D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "POSITION", 1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, offsetToY, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "POSITION", 2, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT, 0, offsetToZ, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
        };
```

---

And how does one call the `deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers` correctly with this type of layout?

Any suggestions? Thank you!